# wicket and AtUnit

Tags: testing, wicket, wicket-tester, atunit

I've started playing with Wicket and I've chosen [Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/) as dependency injection framework.  Now I'm trying to learn how to write a unit test for a WebPage object.

I googled a bit and I've found [this post](http://blog.yanivkessler.com/2010/06/writing-unit-tests-for-guicey-wicket.html) but it mentioned AtUnit so I decided to give it a try.

My WebPage class looks like this

```
public class MyWebPage extends WebPage
{
    @Inject MyService service;
    public MyWebPage()
    {
        //here I build my components and use injected object.
        service.get(id);
        ....    
    }
}
```

I created mock to replace any production MyServiceImpl with it and I guess that Guice in hand with AtUnit should inject it.

Now the problems are:

1. AtUnit expects that I mark target object with @Unit - that is all right as I can pass already created object to WicketTester

   ```
   @Unit MyWebPage page = new MyWebPage();
   wicketTester.startPage(page);
   ```

   but usually I would call startPage with class name.
2. I think AtUnit expects as well that a target object is market with @Inject so AtUnit can create and manage it - but I get an *org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: There is no application attached to current thread main*.  Can I instruct AtUnit to use application from wicketTester?
3. Because I don't use @Inject at MyWebPage (I think) all object that should be injected by Guice are null (in my example the service reference is null)

I really can't find anything about AtUnit inside Wicket environment.  Am I doing something wrong, am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know AtUnit but I use wicket with guice and TestNG. I imagine that AtUnit should work the same way. The important point is the creation of the web application with the use of guice.

Here how I bind all this stuff together for my tests.

I have an abstract base class for all my tests:

```
public abstract class TesterWicket<T extends Component> {

 @BeforeClass
    public void buildMockedTester() {
        System.out.println("TesterWww.buildMockedTester");
        injector = Guice.createInjector(buildModules());
        CoachWebApplicationFactory instance = 
            injector.getInstance(CoachWebApplicationFactory.class);
        WebApplication application = instance.buildWebApplication();
        tester = new WicketTester(application);
    }

protected abstract List<Module> buildModules();
```

The initialization is done for every test class. The subclass defines the necessary modules for the test in the buildModules method.

In my IWebApplicationFactory I add the `GuiceComponentInjector`. That way, after all component instantiation, the fields annotated with @Inject are filled by Guice:

```
public class CoachWebApplicationFactory implements IWebApplicationFactory {

  private static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CoachWebApplicationFactory.class);

  private final Injector injector;

  @Inject
  public CoachWebApplicationFactory(Injector injector) {
      this.injector = injector;
  }

  public WebApplication createApplication(WicketFilter filter) {
    WebApplication app = injector.getInstance(WebApplication.class);
    Application.set(app);
    app.addComponentInstantiationListener(new GuiceComponentInjector(app, injector));
    return app;
  }
}
```

Comment: ok, thanks for sharing this, still thinks that AtUnit it is not best lib to use with WicketTester. I think I will follow your way.